# Unknown Source in Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I keep getting this error message and I can't figure out whats going on. I keep getting the error message "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException" and then is says that my scanners have an unknown source.

Any ideas what's going on?

```
package pizza;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pizza {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double diameter;
    Double radius;
    Double cost;
    Double area;
    final Double costPerInch;

    //Ask and enter diameter
    System.out.println("What is the diameter?");
    Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
    diameter = size.nextDouble();
    size.close();
    radius = diameter / 2;

    //Ask and enter price
    System.out.println("What is the price of the pizza?");
    Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);
    cost = price.nextDouble();
    price.close();

    //Calculate cost per inch
    area = radius * Math.PI;
    costPerInch = cost / area;

    //Output results
    System.out.println("The cost per inch of the pizza is" + costPerInch);
```

Comment: I compiled this fine.  The error comes when I try to input something.  It doesn't like the double being used directly.  Other than that, you should be ok.

Comment: Why are you closing and recreating the scanner?

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this and ran it.  Here is you problem:

```
size.close();
```

Once that closes, it loses the scanner altogether.  Comment out that line, and the code works.